# Make drawer slide down with angular

Tags: css, angularjs

In my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roo9owq3/) at the bottom of the page there will be a footer. If you click on the 'more info' link it hides the div and shows the other.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="footer">
    <div ng-if="!visible" class="footer-bar">
      <a href="" ng-click="toggle()">more info</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="visible" class="footer-drawer">
      <a href="" ng-click="toggle()">hide info</a>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
         Accusamus eos ea impedit perferendis alias sit beatae 
         nulla, at, vitae debitis nesciunt, obcaecati laudantium iure 
         quo voluptatem in assumenda ad doloribus.   
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("footer", [
    function footer() {
        return {
        restrict: "C",

        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            $scope.visible = false;

          $scope.toggle = function toggle() {
            $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
          }
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

What I'm trying to get is a slidedown animation if you toggle the extra info. The page must also slide downwards so that the info is directly visible without scrolling down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use scrollTop() function [.scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and then add watch to your visible value.

There is need to take your content div to your app div to easy access it from jQuery. Refer [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ShankarGurav/nhqh1q7y/)

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .directive("footer", [
    function footer() {
      return {
        restrict: "C",
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          $scope.visible = false;
          $scope.$watchCollection('visible', function(newValue) {
            if (newValue) {
              $(element).parent().parent().scrollTop($(element).parent().parent()[0].scrollHeight);
            }
          });
          $scope.toggle = function toggle() {
            $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
          }
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343832/scroll-to-bottom-in-chat-box-in-angularjs)

Comment: Yes the behaviour is what i want, if i want to animate the slidedown should i do this with css or jquery?

Comment: This is a good answer. Any time you need to do something always try and go native (in this case css) if you can. I am sure this is achievable with CSS3.

Comment: Probably we need to use both css and jquery as div visibility is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

This is work solution with animate and scroll.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/wahcndj0/3/).

```js
angular.module("myApp", ['ngAnimate'])

.directive("footer", ["$timeout",
      function footer($timeout) {
        return {
          restrict: "A",

          link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.visible = false;
            scope.toggle = function toggle() {
              scope.visible = !scope.visible;
              if (scope.visible)
                $timeout(function() {
                    $(document.body).scrollTop($(document.body)[0].scrollHeight)
                  }, 100);
                }
            }
          };
        }
      ]);
```

```css
.sample-show-hide {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}

.sample-show-hide {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1.5s;
  transition: all linear 1.5s;
}

.sample-show-hide.ng-hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, enim. Impedit vitae illo laudantium similique inventore cum, consequatur quae sit dignissimos tempora placeat minus sequi dicta unde ad doloribus cupiditate!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam laborum praesentium non. Dignissimos odit illum hic distinctio libero, adipisci? Dolorum necessitatibus, labore natus similique quaerat tenetur odio quisquam voluptatem saepe.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sapiente delectus itaque rerum exercitationem, pariatur deleniti iusto dolores beatae inventore! Officiis quis asperiores magnam impedit atque quae fugit iste blanditiis!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, enim. Impedit vitae illo laudantium similique inventore cum, consequatur quae sit dignissimos tempora placeat minus sequi dicta unde ad doloribus cupiditate!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam laborum praesentium non. Dignissimos odit illum hic distinctio libero, adipisci? Dolorum necessitatibus, labore natus similique quaerat tenetur odio quisquam voluptatem saepe.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sapiente delectus itaque rerum exercitationem, pariatur deleniti iusto dolores beatae inventore! Officiis quis asperiores magnam impedit atque quae fugit iste blanditiis!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, enim. Impedit vitae illo laudantium similique inventore cum, consequatur quae sit dignissimos tempora placeat minus sequi dicta unde ad doloribus cupiditate!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam laborum praesentium non. Dignissimos odit illum hic distinctio libero, adipisci? Dolorum necessitatibus, labore natus similique quaerat tenetur odio quisquam voluptatem saepe.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sapiente delectus itaque rerum exercitationem, pariatur deleniti iusto dolores beatae inventore! Officiis quis asperiores magnam impedit atque quae fugit iste blanditiis!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero, enim. Impedit vitae illo laudantium similique inventore cum, consequatur quae sit dignissimos tempora placeat minus sequi dicta unde ad doloribus cupiditate!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam laborum praesentium non. Dignissimos odit illum hic distinctio libero, adipisci? Dolorum necessitatibus, labore natus similique quaerat tenetur odio quisquam voluptatem saepe.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio sapiente delectus itaque rerum exercitationem, pariatur deleniti iusto dolores beatae inventore! Officiis quis asperiores magnam impedit atque quae fugit iste blanditiis!</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div footer>
      <button ng-click="toggle()"><span ng-show="visible">hide info</span><span ng-show="!visible">more info</span></button>
      <div ng-show="visible" class="sample-show-hide">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus eos ea impedit perferendis alias sit beatae nulla, at, vitae debitis nesciunt, obcaecati laudantium iure quo voluptatem in assumenda ad doloribus.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-init="checked=true">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"> Is Visible...
    </label>
    <div class="sample-show-hide" ng-show="checked" style="clear:both;">
      Visible...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```