# How to do $anchorscroll in Angular 1 for a div that is dynamic (repeated element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i have a chat messaging app I'm working on. I have a div that has overflow-y set to auto, but the thing is, when I run the script, it shows me the top messages, so every time the fetch request is invoked ($scope.chatRoomMsgs) , the top messages are shown. I would like it to scroll to the bottom of the list every time the fetch request is invoked.

```
var app = angular.module("chatApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('ChatController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.chatroom_id;
$scope.chatRoomMsgs = function(id) {
    $scope.chatroom_id = id;
    $http.get("readMessages.php?chatroom_id=" + id).success(function(msgs) {
        $scope.chat = msgs;
    });
}
});
```

Here is the front end. The li tag is repeated for every message. Div #messages is the container.

```
        <div id="messages" class="compressed">
            <ul id="test" ng-repeat="x in chat | filter : {'initial_message':'N'} | orderBy : 'message_id'">
                <li class="{{ x.class }}">
                    <span class="{{ x.status }}">{{ x.sender }}</span>
                    <span class="time">{{ x.timestamp | date : "EEE d MMM h:mm a"}}</span>
                    <br>
                    <span id="message" class="message" ng-bind-html="x.message"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I'm open to different solutions that may include jquery.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the ScrollTop attribute of the div that holds the messages

```
var chatBox = document.getElementById('messages');
chatBox.scrollTop = 300 + 8 + ($scope.chat.length * 240);
```

*Something similar to this*, I would play with the number a bit though, I don't have a working model of what you are trying to work with, so the numbers may be off.

Here is the Accepted Answer from the post where I got the above code --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344313/1214743

you may want to take a look around at what other people are doing, it appears that there may be an easier way to do what you are trying to do.

I would Google "Angular Chat Scroller" if I were you.